# How to skip-name-resolve in Mysql8 and use IPs instead?

Tags: mysql, mysql8

I'm trying to disable the DNS name resolving as I have many other servers connecting to the central database. The DNS resolving is slow and can apparently be disabled like this:

```
[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
port=3412
max_connections=500
skip-name-resolve
```

However I still can connect to it via localhost, which doesn't make sense to me.

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p -P 3412
```

I have done some research [here](https://nixcp.com/skip-name-resolve/):

> If you choose to use skip-name-resolve, make sure your MYSQL
> connection privileges are set to allow IPs, and not hosts.
>
> On most systems, for the local MySQL Server you will need to use
> host=127.0.0.1 for ipv4 and  host=::1 for ipv6 networks, instead of
> the classic “host=localhost”.

Why can I still connect via localhost if DNS resolving is disabled?

Comment: You didn't show what are your actual user privileges. It could be 'root'@'%' which accepts any host.

Comment: localhost is not in DNS, it is in your hosts-file (/etc/hosts)

Comment: @AlexD yes, it's `root@%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL treats connecting to `localhost` specially. In this case it connects via a UNIX domain socket, not via TCP, and the string `localhost` is still used for user authentication.

Comment: I see. Do I have to replace `socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` with `bind-address=*` ? (I want to allow both IPv4 and Ipv6)

Comment: @Houman What are you trying to do? This is completely irrelevant to skipping name resolution. You can leave it as is.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood your reply.  Is there any other way to check if the DNS resolving is truly disabled?

Comment: @Houman Try connecting to `::1` or `127.0.0.1` instead and `SELECT current_user();` ? Or, for that matter, connect from the remote host that led you to begin this adventure initially.

Comment: But I can do `mysql -h ::1 -u root -P 2333 -p` despite having commented out `skip-name-resolve`. I think the reason is that as Alex mentioned `root@%` and anything can access it.

Comment: The reason this got my attention was this error shown in error.log: `[Server] IP address '185.xx.xx.xx' has been resolved to the host name 'xx.xxx.xxx.185.xxhost.com', which resembles IPv4-address itself.`. I have to apply this to see if these errors will stop appearing. And I wanted a way to test it first.

Comment: @Houman Connect from a remote host yourself, then.

Comment: Thanks. That was a great idea. I didn't see the wood for the trees. Need a break. :)